# RECORD_AUDIO and CAMERA permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app that takes pictures and records audio but using separate apps (via intent) do I need to add and handle RECORD_AUDIO and CAMERA permissions in my app or it's everything in those separate apps?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: You may need storage permissions if you want to read those audio and image from Device Storage.

Answer (score 0):

It asks permission for accessing a camera app and you are open camera inside your app

Answer (score 0):

You can ask permission on Runtime as below

```
  // Requesting permission to RECORD_AUDIO
    private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
    private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();

    }
```

and in onCreate()

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
```